# Get the style of html checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I need to create a div with same style as an Html checkbox, but by inspecting the checkbox I am not getting the exact styles, is there any way I can replicate the style of checkbox (background and border) to a div or a span

[image]

I need the span with + sign with the same style as a checkbox

Expanded view

[image]

collapsed view

[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to help with this when you have provided none of the code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: I can't believe this is possible. Especially, because each browser has its own style. what is your goal?

Comment: the first item is a checkbox, the second item is a toggle for collapsible (span), i need the toggle and the checkbox should look the same @MoshFeu

Comment: I understand. But why cant you use an actual checkbox?

Comment: @MoshFeu edited the question with what I am doing

Comment: this can give you basic idea: https://codepen.io/nikkz/pen/BzVBJo

Comment: I don't think that there is a "straight" way to do this. But you can do some hack and put an unchecked checkbox "in background" and add the plus icon on top of it. If you're interesting, I can show show you how

Comment: @MoshFeu I think it's better to go with a custom checkbox

Comment: I thought that you want to keep the browser's style. But if you like custom checkbox, that's great :)